# PA15 doesn't work as GPIO even after Enabling GPIO_Remap_SWJ_JTAGDisable

Tags: stm32, keil

My MCU is STM32F107. My main program works fine with using different peripherals and function. In my program a very simple task makes me crazy. I need to use PA15 as GPIO (The simplest task:) )
I enabled

```
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA,ENABLE);        
    GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_JTAGDisable,ENABLE);

    GPIOStruc.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIOStruc.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIOStruc.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIOStruc);
```

but it doesn't change the pin state with Set and Reset GPIO.  Other GPIOS work fine.
what is my mistake?

Comment: Does PinRemapConfig use AFIO? Is AFIO peripheral clock enabled?

Comment: How are you setting bit?  Unsigned int?

Comment: Thanks Justme and StainlessSteelRat, Justme your comment helped me a lot. I've forgotten to enable AFIO. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As  the Justme told me I had to enable AFIO before GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_JTAGDisable,ENABLE);
line.

Comment: Pin remapping is done via AFIO and therefore AFIO peripheral clock needs to be enabled before using it.